# Blender Bake Normal Map Problem

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I've baked(using Cycles) a normal map from a hi-poly (sculpted mesh) to a low-poly mesh which is shrinkwraped to hi-poly. It looked fine, but I needed to add some geometry (loop cuts) to my mesh. After I've done this and baked normal map again, some artifacts appeared in the parts where geometry has been added(you can see artifacts on pic).

[image]

Comment: See what changed on the UV map and go from there. Perhaps there are now overlapping islands which make baking bake over itself.

Comment: But is it possible if I've unwrapped it again after adding new loop cuts?

Comment: It's going to be speculation without more info about your UV map and what you did aside from that. Post screenshot of UV map (same as above of these islands as well), post a blend file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and [edit] your question with all that info so to make this question clearer.

Comment: I have solved this problem by separating individual parts of my mesh.